# .SEC to .MP4 or .AVI

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm attempting to convert samsung DVR footage of a police interrogation/questioning to a more usable format such as mp4 or avi. I'm able to get the .sec to convert to either format but the audio doesn't make it through with the video. I can't seem to figure it out... I'm also an idiot.

Here's the command I'm using which results in video's converting fine, but no audio.

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i INPUT.sec -filter:v "setpts=1*PTS" OUTPUT.avi
```

Comment: You specify that the input format is a raw H264 (video) stream. If that is accurate, there is no audio.

Comment: run `ffprobe` on the file and show us the output. That will tell us if there is audio.

Comment: Try to view it with the [Samsung SmartViewer](https://www.hanwhasecurity.com/smart-viewer.html). If it's a Samsung Security video file, then this is the best viewer for the format.

Comment: Not sure if this is the output you are looking for from ffprobe: Input #0, h264, from '12590100.sec':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 352x240, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc

Comment: Tried the Samsung Smartviewer, couldn't figure out how to import files.

Comment: All of the files have an .exe in the folder that allows me to view the videos and they all have audio in that player. The issues is I need to be able edit these videos hence the need to be able to convert them to avi or mp4.

Comment: If there is only a `Stream #0:0` and no `Stream #0:1` then you have a video only file with no audio. You should edit at least the last section from `Input #0` into the body of your question to be certain.

Comment: Copy and paste **all** text from the ffprobe output.